# Java - enum - como crear un método que compruebe los valores

Tags: java, enum

He definido el siguiente `enum` con las posiciones de los jugadores en el campo.

Quiero asociar las posiciones a colores mediante `getColor` y lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Position {

    enum Position{
         GOALKEEPER, DEFENDER, MIDFIELDER, FORWARD;
    }

    public String getColor(Position position) {
        switch (position){
            case GOALKEEPER:
                return "BLACK";
            case DEFENDER:
                return "RED";
            case MIDFIELDER:
                return "GREEN";
            case FORWARD:
                return "BLUE";
        }
    }   // error - missing return statement
}
```

Los test que debo pasar son los siguientes:

```
void testGetColor() {

        position = Position.GOALKEEPER;
        assertEquals("BLACK", position.getColor());

        position = Position.DEFENDER;
        assertEquals("RED", position.getColor());

        position = Position.MIDFIELDER;
        assertEquals("GREEN", position.getColor());

        position = Position.FORWARD;
        assertEquals("BLUE", position.getColor());
}
```

Tengo un error *`missing return statement`* (que lo indico dentro del código) pero no entiendo por qué si en cada caso hago un `return`

Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes añadir un caso `default`: en el `switch`. Por ejemplo:

```
    switch (position){
        case GOALKEEPER:
            return "BLACK";
        case DEFENDER:
            return "RED";
        case MIDFIELDER:
            return "GREEN";
        case FORWARD:
            return "BLUE";
        default:
            return "NO-COLOR";// O throw new RuntimeException("Posicion no valida")

    }
```

Si no, el `switch` puede tener casos sin retorno, y es lo que provoca el error.

Saludos !